# Why is memcpy() randomly not copying the correct value?

Tags: c

I'm a senior studying computer science and I've never seen behavior this strange before. I'm sure there is just some C complexity that I'm not understanding but I'm completely lost right now.

I’ve made the following function:

**Declaration**

```
void parse_resp(unsigned char *resp, unsigned char *chunk, unsigned int *opcode, unsigned char *opparams, unsigned int *nonce, unsigned char *treasure, int *offset);
```

*Basically just a function where I pass a punch of pointers to get populated*

**Definition**

```
void parse_resp(unsigned char *resp, unsigned char *chunk, unsigned int *opcode, unsigned char *opparams, unsigned int *nonce, unsigned char *treasure, int *offset)
{
    int chunklen = resp[0];
    memcpy(&chunk[0], &resp[1], chunklen);
    memcpy(opcode, &resp[chunklen + 1], 1);
    memcpy(&opparams[0], &resp[chunklen + 2], 2);
    memcpy(nonce, &resp[chunklen + 4], 4);
    *nonce = htonl(*nonce);
}
```

**Variable Initialization**

```
unsigned char treasure[1024];
int offset = 0;
unsigned char chunk[127];
unsigned int opcode;
unsigned char opparams[2];
unsigned int nonce;
```

But here’s where it gets weird.
If I call the function like this `parse_resp(buf, chunk, &opcode, opparams, &nonce, NULL, &offset);` Then everything works fine.
But if I pass in treasure as an argument (even though parse_resp doesn’t use treasure)  then  `memcpy(opcode, &resp[chunklen + 1], 1);` doesn’t work. Printing the value of opcode after this shows some random int . This makes no sense to me. I don’t understand how passing treasure as an argument could make memcpy behave incorrectly. If I print the value of `resp[chunklen + 1]`, I see a 0 (as expected), but when I try to `memcpy()` that same location, I get a random number? Any idea what is going on here?

**Note**: I realize there are fairly easy work arounds for this error, but I would like to understand what is going on first.

Comment: Please put together a [mcve] so we can see the issue you're having.

Comment: You are memcpy'ing one byte into an `int`. (`opcode`). That has a bad smell. Has that variable been initialised? If not, you've got some unspecified behaviour going on, at least.

Comment: <O/T> Consider grouping all these fields in a `struct`.. it will be more organized and make the argument-passing easier to read IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`opcode` has type `int` which is most likely 4 bytes, however you're only copying a single byte into it:

```
memcpy(opcode, &resp[chunklen + 1], 1);
```

So the other 3 bytes are left uninitialized and therefore have *indeterminate values*.  So at best there is no guarantee that these bytes have any particular value, and changing how `parse_resp` is called is enough to vary the values of those uninitialized bytes.

In some cases reading an uninitialized variable can trigger [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), however since `opcode` had its address taken it's not an issue (unless you're on an exotic architecture that has trap representations for `int`).

Change the type of this variable and the associated parameter to `unsigned char`.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Then I guess I could cast that `unsigned char` to an `int` later? I still find it strange that my code only stops working when I pass in that extra variable `treasure`.

Comment: @DallinDavis There's no need to cast since any value an `unsigned char` can hold can also be stored in an `int`, and because it will be promoted to type `int` in most cases.